# Setup and Teardown actions in Blazemeter

Tags: logging, performance-testing, blazemeter

Does anyone know how to add steps to a Blazemeter test that are executed before the actual load testing component (i.e. Setup and Teardown steps). Is this possible? Currently we're having to add these steps in JMeter script, but we want to try and do as much as possible in Blazemeter. What we're trying to do is the following:

1. Do a POST API call to our logging server to state that testing has started.
2. Execute the load test script.
3. Do another POST API call to our logging server to state testing has finished.

I've had a look online and on other posts, but haven't seen anything like this mentioned, so I'm wondering if it's even possible or not. I'm pretty new to Blazemeter, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlazeMeter naturally supports JMeter .jmx test scripts so just add setUp and tearDown thread groups normally, save your script and upload it to BlazeMeter - it will run it exactly as it's defined.

[image]

More information: [How to Use the SetUp Thread Group in JMeter When Preparing a Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test)

Comment: Thanks for that, I was wondering if it was possible without the use of JMeter scripts, but from what I've read its pretty much universally accepted that this can only be done via a script. Thanks for confirming!